# The 3.5 inch raspberry pi 4B screen does not work error Cmakelists.txtprojects()

Tags: linux, raspbian

During the installation of the screen drivers.

- The image is not sent to the screen.
- The Raspberry reboots.
- The image is still displayed on the screen as shown in the attached image below.

**Warning**

> CMaki Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
>
> No project() command is present. The top-level CMakeLists.txt file
> must contain a literal, direct call to the project() command. Add a
> line of code such as project (ProjectName)near the top of the file,
> but after cmake_minimum_required().
>
> CMake is pretending there is a "**project (Project)**" command on the
> first line.
> This warning is for project developers. **Use-Wno-dev** to suppress it.

Please understand that I am new to the world of **Raspberrys**  and can't do much to solve the problem. Do you have any suggestion on what I should do?[image: IMAGE ATTACHMENT]

I tried reinstalling "**Raspbian**" and other drivers, but the same warning and the same result.